# Why is the logo not spinning forever?

Tags: css, reactjs, css-animations

TSX:

```
function Content() {
  return (
    <>
    <main id="main">
        <img src="/vite.svg" id="logo" />
    </main>
    </>
  );
}

export default Content;
```

CSS:

```css
:root {
  font-family:  sans-serif, Arial !important;
}

#main #logo {
  animation-name: spin;
}

@keyframes spin {
  from {
    transform: rotateY(0);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotateY(360);
  }
}
```

I tried nothing and was expecting the react logo spin animation but on the vite image.

Comment: You need to specify [`animation-duration`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-duration) and [`animation-iteration-count`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-iteration-count) (e.g. `spin 2s infinite`). Also, `rotateY(360)` should be `rotateY(360deg)`.

Comment: Like what??????

Comment: Sorry if I didn't made it clear: `animation: spin 2s infinite` or `animation-name: spin; animation-duration: 2s; animation-iteration-count: infinite;`

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to provide it the count like the following snippet:

```css
#logo {
  animation: spin 1000ms;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you need to specify that for how long you want to make the logo animate.

```
animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
```

Here, spin is your animation name, 2s is the interval in which one spin gets completed, linear is the timing function and infinite is the iteration count. Add this line after your "to{} block".

Answer (score 1):

[CSS animations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations/Using_CSS_animations) require additional information outside of the animation name. A functioning CSS animation would look like this:

```css
p {
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-name: spin;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
}
```

But this is typically written in shorthand:

```css
#main #logo {
  animation: 3s infinite linear spin;
}

@keyframes spin { 
  100% { 
    transform: rotateY(360deg); 
  } 
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <img id="logo" src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/300"/>
</div>
```